# How do I map a keybinding to a command?

Tags: vim

I am currently trying out Clion from intellij but I am not a big fan of keybindings but it offers vim support. For example  Clion has a keybinding ctrl+shift+n to open a fuzzy search.

Is it possible to bind a keybinding to a custom command in vim?

Something like

```
command :fuzzy <C-N>
```

Comment: is it an intellij question or vim question? do you mean the ideavim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IdeaVim is not Vim. There is no reason whatsoever to expect anything to work in IdeaVim like in Vim or vice-versa so… do you want that mapping to work in Vim or in IdeaVim? If your question is about Vim, your CLion explanation and tags are totally irrelevant.

In Vim, you would put this line in `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <key> :Command<CR>
```

See `:help key-notation` for `<key>` and note that Vim doesn't make a difference between `<C-N>` and `<C-n>`.

Now, Vim has no "fuzzy" capability on its own, so you will need a third party plugin for that.

Comment: @MaikKlein, but what it does with what it reads from your `~/.vimrc` is pretty much unknown.

Comment: That's why I would create a standalone vimrc file just for ideavim

Comment: No, that's why you would create a custom mapping in CLion's prefs.

Comment: @MaikKlein I believe that idea vim uses a `~/.ideavimrc` not `~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you'll enjoy Vim without a preference for (fast and efficient) keybindings, but this is certainly possible, if somewhat odd. Usually, one defines keybindings for custom commands (so the other way around), in order to speed up frequently used commands.

To do the opposite, you have to consider the modes: (Custom) commands take *Ex commands*, whereas keybindings usually are in *normal mode*. Fortunately, there's the built-in `:normal` command to bridge between the two of them. And to use the special keycodes (like `<C-N>`), you need `:execute`:

```
:command FuzzySearch execute "normal \<C-N>"
```

Note that this probably only works in Vim itself, not in emulations (like in Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA), as those typically only offer a subset of the full Vim functionality.